# Function not being initialized

Tags: jquery

I am facing a very odd problem. Everything should work correctly, however, the function refuses to run.

I have similar functions that run just fine but this will not initialize unless I run it through the console.

This is the code:

```
$(".like").click(function() {
    number = parseInt($(this).text());
    $(this).text(number+1).addClass("iLike").removeClass("like");
    delete number;
});

$(".iLike").click(function() {
    number = parseInt($(this).text());
    $(this).text(number-1).addClass("like").removeClass("iLike");
    delete number;
});
```

The site I am trying to run it @ is: ~~~~

It is in the scripts but, it's not running. I don't know why.

HTML:

```
<button id="like-85" class="like " type="button">3</button>
```

Problem: Injecting HTML into the DOM would not alter the source and would not attached certain functions to the injection.

Solution: Insert within the tag, which is , an event such as onclick:

Comment: It's probably not in your $(document).ready(). Can you post your HTML? Maybe it's a problem with your selector.

Comment: have you inspected it in chrome's console? what did you get>

Comment: I added the code to the $(document).ready(). That was a no go. I am using the Chrome Console to check for errors. The function will not run unless I initialize it from the console.

Comment: @Anraiki- check my my answer. I looked at the source from the page on the link you provided. I didn't find any elements with a `like` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked the source. You don't have any elements on that page with a class `like` or `iLike`. So basically, you're binding the `click()` to nothing.

**Update:** It seems that you're adding the button element to the apge via js? If so, change `click( function() ..` to `.on('click',function() ..`

i.e.

```
$(".like").on('click', function() {
    number = parseInt($(this).text());
    $(this).text(number+1).addClass("iLike").removeClass("like");
    delete number;
});

$(".iLike").on('click', function() {
    number = parseInt($(this).text());
    $(this).text(number-1).addClass("like").removeClass("iLike");
    delete number;
});
```

Documentation:
http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Woah! When I compare this to the developer's tool the Div box is not empty but in the sources it is!

Comment: Are you adding the class programmatically via javascript? You might then want to change the `click()` to `.on('click', function() ..` })`

Comment: Yes. I am. Is there something I have to do to get my function to work if I am using such a solution?

Comment: Tried the new code function, which I also applied to the $(document).ready(). Still not working.

Comment: Found another route and solution. I attached a onclick="someFunction();" to the <button> tag.

Comment: You don't need `delete number;`, but you do need `var number = ...`.

Answer (score 1):

It has to be inside the `$(document).ready()`